# What is the best (safest) way to augment the URL used by UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

We are developing a hybrid application for iOS.  Most of the application is a WebApp running within a UIWebView.  It is sometimes necessary for the native portion of the application to modify the URL, adding some parameters.  I'm aware there are "alternate" solutions we could use (e.g. native app talks to our server independently of the webview); however, I'm primarily interested in a good & safe solution to URL augmentation.

I've been looking for the "best" technique to do this, and found two that appear to (mostly) work.

**Technique #1 - re-initialize the URL**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"GOTO: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
    NSURL * oldurl = request.URL;
    [[request URL] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&newParam=dave", [oldurl absoluteString]]];
    return YES;
}
```

**Technique #2 - reject the 1st URL, and sub-in a new one**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL * oldurl = request.URL;
    if ([self isFixed:oldurl]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSURL * newurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&newParam=dave", [oldurl absoluteString]]];
        [theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newurl]];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Technique #2 seems to cause artifacts on some pages ("iFrame load interrupted", maybe other issues).

I'm curious if anyone else has done url replacement like this, or via another technique, or if anyone is is aware of problems with technique #1 (which I'll hopefully use).

I know method swizzling is not recommended, and Apple's document recommends against subclassing UIWebView.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Whoops - technique #1 doesn't actually work.  My actual code was doing more than I posted, and it only appeared to work...  This is probably good news, since it was a little more evil that I'd like.

Comment: If you want to add a parameter to a URL this code is a bit more solid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026916/passing-arguments-into-url-string-objective-c/7027608#7027608

Comment: Ah, I'll give those tricks a try.  A little worried there was no accepted solution in that post.

Comment: @Jano, thanks for the suggestion; however, your other answer is simply crafting a new URL.  What I need to do is update the URL that will be used by the UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never call an `-init` method on an object that has already been initialized. This is not defined behavior. It is quite likely that you are leaking memory here since the old request ivars are probably not released correctly.

Something similar to the second approach is generally preferred.

Another approach is to use `NSURLProtocol` to inject yourself into the URL loading process. Doing it that way, you can create your own `NSURLConnection` using a modified `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: I'd like to explore this more, since I think it's probably the most "correct" solution.  Unfortunately, under the gun a bit, and am using my own technique #2 for the moment.  Perhaps I'll have time to try this approach and can return and comment on it.  (At the moment, don't fully understand those APIs, so any additional pointers would be appreciated.)

Comment: I should probably write a blog post about NSURLProtocol. It's very useful stuff. Take a look at `ProxyURLProtocol` for an example of something very close to what you'd do. See how in `initWithRequest:...` I rewrite the request similar to how you're describing? https://github.com/PandoraBoy/PandoraBoy/blob/master/ProxyURLProtocol.m

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to try out. I was playing with the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`, and found out I could do this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *oldUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", request.URL.absoluteURL];

    if ([oldUrlString isEqualToString:@"http://www.google.com/"])
    {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location = \"http://www.arstechnica.com\""];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I managed to redirect using a javascript injection, the first request to www.google.com is rejected, and redirected to www.arstechnica.com (I just picked a random site).

I think it's slightly better than hot-swapping the URL on the fly.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought I might use js injection to re-write some of the anchors on page load.  This looks like it would work as well and may be cleaner than technique #2.